# How to set up an old laptop as a wireless terminal to the desktop

Tags: command-line, ssh, laptop, multi-user

I have searched countless phrases to find an answer and can't quite figure this one out. It is to my understanding that (as it was many moons ago at universities and the like) you can still use one central setup to do the processing/video/account/file management and have terminals to access it that merely function as a screen, keyboard, and mouse which to provide input back to the main PC.

SSH is an easy way to do this from a command line point of view, but I have a few old laptops that would function excellent as terminals, while leaving the load to my self-proclaimed super computer... Ex: My significant other has an old Dell mini 10... The thing is total garbage, even for surfing the web, EVEN AFTER a factory reset... but it does have a decent processor and a Gig of RAM. I was thinking to do a minimal ubuntu install and then lxde or e17 or the like for a DE... but what might be better is to keep it a command line variant that can let the desktop take the burden and just use it as a terminal...

This would benefit me more, I think, because it would allow the laptops to run smoothly (I have a few of them I'd like to revive through this cause) but more so I can manage all user accounts, homes directories, and installed applications right from one system...

I am by no means a Linux pro, but even if no one has time to tell me step by step, even a push in the right direction with which programs to use would mean a lot to me. I'm guessing this goes a step beyond SSH and involves so kind of setup with an X server, but again, I'm guessing =)

**Here's what I'm looking for summarized:**
I would like to, from any ubuntu device, have it set up so that when booted, it will connect to the desktop. Then they can proceed to use the laptop as a terminal and connect to the desktop as if they were sitting in front of the screen/keyboard/mouse attached to it.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. It is highly suggested to provide your solution as a new answer. Also please change the title back to the original.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## I have found the answer to my own question;

## https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultiseatX

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at the Linux Terminal Server Project for "Thin Client" type solution: http://www.ltsp.org/

Comment: I have checked into LTSP and Thinstation, but either seems to be getting away from the simplified solution I'm looking for... It seems like something that could just as easily be done through already available packages... Linux was developed with multi-user functionality at it's heart to begin with, I believe (if my history knowledge is correct) that even unix was developed this way... seems oddly strange that it's not a common enough topic to have been able to find the information I needed via Google... Perhaps I am delving too far into ancient concepts. I read this from another member:

Comment: "My suggestion is a minimal ubuntu server install and then, if you're skilled, pure command line, otherwise a light fluxbox and a little eyecandy with wbar. I use this little beast as a terminal client to access my desktop when I'm in the kitchen or in the bathroom and I need to surf the web or similar stuff."
-Pitto

Comment: A simple install on the laptop with a minimal X and then have the users ssh (could be semi-automated with .bash_login)  to the "server" and they start and run a desktop there using the laptop's X server as remote display. Here's a simple run-through: http://www.hungry.com/~jamie/xexport.html